# How to give the serial number if data is repeating

Tags: sql

if My table has this values i need to generate seqno column

```
ClientId clinetLocation seqno
001        Abc           1
001        BBc           2
001        ccd           3
002        Abc           1
002        BBc           2
003        ccd           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `row_number()` function:

```
select ClientId, clinetLocation,
       row_number() over (partition by ClientId order by clinetLocation) as seqnum
from t;
```

This is a standard function available in most databases.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

One option would be counting the grouped rows with respect to those columns :

```
select count(1) over ( order by ClientId, ClientLocation ) as seqno, 
       ClientId, ClientLocation
  from tab
 group by ClientId, ClientLocation;
```

*where `ClientId` & `ClientLocation` combination seems unique.*

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/ZPJ35367)